# Render JSX in react native

Tags: react-native

Let's say we have a jsx saved in a variable, can we render it in react native?

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const content = `<View style={styles.container}>
  <Text>TESTING</Text>
</View>`;

const App = () => {
  return {content};
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
});

export default App;
```

[image]

Getting the above error if I run that code.

How to implement this? Any example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to convert it into a string, then.
You could use just like this.

```
const content = <View style={styles.container}>
  <Text>TESTING</Text>
</View>;

const App = () => {
  return content;
};
```

Comment: Actually I am getting a string from backend so need to render that string as it is.

Comment: why are you sending JSX from backends as strings in a react-native app? What about the CSS? Are they inline?

Comment: why are you sending JSX from backends as strings in a react-native app?

Comment: Thats the use case (cannot tell what exactly it is for)

Comment: Something like this :- https://github.com/acornjs/acorn-jsx